# Laravel - localhost redirected you too many times - middleware not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I created a middleware to redirect users to a certain webpage unless a certain user is logged in. I also want to include an exception to which routes this middleware applies. Yet, I get the error 'localhost redirected you too many times'. Why is this happening? Here is my code:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/lanzamiento', function () {
    return view('coming-soon');
})->name('coming.soon');
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\ComingSoon::class,
];
```

**ComingSoon.php** (the Middleware I created)

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class ComingSoon
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if (!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->route('coming.soon');
      }
      if (Auth::user()->email != 'joaquin@test.com') {
        return redirect()->route('coming.soon');
      }
      return $next($request);
    }

protected $except = [
  '/lanzamiento'
];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

** EDIT - ROUTE LIST **

```
+--------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method                                 | URI                                                             | Name                            | Action                                                                          | Middleware   |
+--------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD                               | /                                                               |                                 | Closure                                                                         | web          |
|        | POST                                   | alquilar/detallealquiler/{id}/{horariollegada}/{horariopartida} | alquiler.detalle                | App\Http\Controllers\EspaciosController@detalleAlquiler                         | web          |
|        | POST                                   | alquilar/disponible/{id}/{horariollegada}/{horariopartida}      | alquiler.disponible             | App\Http\Controllers\EspaciosController@disponible                              | web          |
|        | POST                                   | alquilar/{id}                                                   | alquilar                        | App\Http\Controllers\AlquileresController@alquilar                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | anfitrion                                                       |                                 | Closure                                                                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | api/user                                                        |                                 | Closure                                                                         | api,auth:api |
|        | POST                                   | cargar-vehiculo/datos                                           | create.upload.vehicle           | App\Http\Controllers\UploadVehicleController@UploadVehicle                      | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | cargar-vehiculo/datos                                           | show.upload.vehicle             | App\Http\Controllers\UploadVehicleController@showUploadVehicle                  | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | cargar-vehiculo/datos/editar/{id?}                              | show.edit.vehicle               | App\Http\Controllers\UploadVehicleController@showEditVehicle                    | web,auth     |
|        | PUT                                    | cargar-vehiculo/datos/editar/{id}                               | edit.vehicle                    | App\Http\Controllers\UploadVehicleController@editVehicle                        | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE                                 | cargar-vehiculo/datos/{id}                                      | delete.vehicle                  | App\Http\Controllers\UploadVehicleController@deleteVehicle                      | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | creditos                                                        |                                 | Closure                                                                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | espacio/{id}                                                    | show.espacio                    | App\Http\Controllers\EspaciosController@showEspacio                             | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | faqs                                                            |                                 | Closure                                                                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | home                                                            | home                            | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                                       | web          |
|        | POST                                   | lanzamiento                                                     |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\ContactController@sendContact                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | lanzamiento                                                     | coming.soon                     | Closure                                                                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | login                                                           | login                           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                         | web,guest    |
|        | POST                                   | login                                                           |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                                 | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | login/{provider}                                                |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SocialAuthController@redirectToProvider               | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | login/{provider}/callback                                       |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback           | web,guest    |
|        | POST                                   | logout                                                          | logout                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | mantenimiento                                                   |                                 | Closure                                                                         | web          |
|        | POST                                   | password/email                                                  | password.email                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail           | web,guest    |
|        | POST                                   | password/reset                                                  |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                         | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | password/reset                                                  | password.request                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm          | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | password/reset/{token}                                          | password.reset                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm                 | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | perfil                                                          | profile                         | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@mostrarPerfil                            | web,auth     |
|        | POST                                   | perfil/editar-imagen                                            | update_profile_image            | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@updateProfileImage                       | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | perfil/editar-imagen                                            | show.update.profile.image       | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@showUpdateProfileImage                   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | politica-y-privacidad                                           |                                 | Closure                                                                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | quienes-somos                                                   |                                 | Closure                                                                         | web          |
|        | POST                                   | register                                                        |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                           | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | register                                                        | register                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm               | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | resultados                                                      | show.search                     | App\Http\Controllers\EspaciosController@search                                  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | signin                                                          |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                         | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | signup                                                          |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm               | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | testfunction                                                    | test                            | App\Http\Controllers\EspaciosController@test                                    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | upload-espacio/diasyhorarios/{espacio}                          | upload.espacio.3                | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@showUploadEspacio3                 | web,auth     |
|        | PUT                                    | upload-espacio/diasyhorarios/{id}                               | insert.upload.espacio.3         | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@insertAndShowUploadEspacio3        | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE                                 | upload-espacio/espacio/{id}                                     | delete.espacio                  | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@deleteEspacio                      | web,auth     |
|        | POST                                   | upload-espacio/estadias                                         | create.espacio.upload.espacio.2 | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@createEspacioAndShowUploadEspacio2 | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | upload-espacio/estadias/{espacio}                               | upload.espacio.2                | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@showUploadEspacio2                 | web,auth     |
|        | PUT                                    | upload-espacio/estadias/{id}                                    | insert.upload.espacio.2         | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@insertAndShowUploadEspacio2        | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS | upload-espacio/infogeneral/editar/{espacio}                     | editar.upload.espacio.1         | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@showEditarUploadEspacio1           | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE                                 | upload-espacio/infogeneral/eliminarfoto/{id}                    | deletepic.upload.espacio        | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@deletePicEspacio                   | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | upload-espacio/infogeneral/{espacio?}                           | upload.espacio.1                | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@showUploadEspacio1                 | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | upload-espacio/precios/{espacio}                                | upload.espacio.4                | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@showUploadEspacio4                 | web,auth     |
|        | PUT                                    | upload-espacio/precios/{id}                                     | insert.upload.espacio.4         | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@insertAndShowUploadEspacio4        | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | upload-espacio/resumen/{espacio}                                | upload.espacio.resumen          | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@showUploadEspacioResumen           | web,auth     |
|        | PUT                                    | upload-espacio/resumen/{id}                                     | insert.upload.espacio.resumen   | App\Http\Controllers\UploadEspacioController@insertAndShowUploadEspacioResumen  | web,auth     |
+--------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please show results of `php artisan route:list` or full routes file.

Comment: You should probably register the middleware inside `$routeMiddleware` and give it a name and probably use group middleware except login. Currently the middleware checks if its logged in or not and redirects to `coming.soon` route again which is why there are too many redirects

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that when you redirect, user again comes to the server and hits the same middleware. You should check route name to exclude that. You must write exclude logic by yourself.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class ComingSoon
{
    protected $exceptRoutes = [
        'coming.soon'
    ];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $route = $request->route()->getName();

      if(!in_array($route, $this->exceptRoutes)) {
          if (!Auth::check() or Auth::user()->email !== 'joaquin@test.com') {
            return redirect()->route('coming.soon');
          }
      }
      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition means that only logged in `joaquin` user is able to log in.

Comment: When I do that I get a "Call to a member function getName() on null" error. I checked $request->route() and it returns null

Comment: Which laravel version? `Null` for requesting any page?

Comment: Laravel 5.5. Yeah, any page. I tried different ways of getting the route and they all return null. Weird, right?

Comment: Are you sure the previous middleware passes `$request` with `$next` call correct?

Comment: What have you tried? `Route::currentRouteName()` and `Request::route()->getName()`? Sorry, I can't help with that, it seems it must work. https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-55-get-route-name-in-controller-view-and-middleware